# Getting Workflow by a SPListItem

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

My question is simple. I created a SPListItem programmatically then I need to invoke a custom workflow programmatically. For that I want to get this newly created workflow instance's ID to save in SPListItem created earlier.

How do I achieve this ?

Kindly help as soon as possible

Comment: This should be possible. I need to clarrify this before answering your question. What do you mean by "Workflow instance's ID to save in SPListItem created earlier". Do you need to get the SPLIstItems Id to invoke a workflow.?

Comment: No, I have SPListItem ID for the item that I need to invoke workflow on. But what I want is once I have invoked a workflow on a SPListItem a workflow item is created in Workflow Tasks SPList. I want ID of that Workflow item or that workflow splistitem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://rehmangul.wordpress.com/2010/09/30/start-a-workflow-programmatically/) is how to start a workflow on `SPListItem`. After you start the workflow, you can retrieve its instance from the [`SPListItem.Workflows property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.workflows%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Workflow instance ID can be obtained from the [`SPWorkflow.InstanceId` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflow.instanceid%28v=office.14%29.aspx).